# Passport not working properly in NodeJS backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, google-authentication

I am pretty new in the world of NodeJS and my Javascript knowledge can be accurately described as noob+ . Don't laugh at me for failing at something (seemingly) this simple!

I've been trying for a couple of days to make a NodeJS backend support Google authorization using Passport.

The plan was to redirect the response to a certain page, but it doesn't work for some reason.

The relevant codes look like this:

```
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = "...........................................";
const GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = "..................";
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback"
    },
    function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile.id);}
));
```

and

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = express.Router();
const passportConfig = require('./Config/passport.config');
const blogapp = express();

blogapp.use(cors()); 
blogapp.use(express.static('public'));
blogapp.use(passport.initialize());
blogapp.use(passport.session());
blogapp.use(router);
.
.
.
.
.
.

blogapp.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login' ]}));

blogapp.get( '/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate( 'google', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/loginfailed'
    }));
```

It successfully prints the profile.id, yet does not proceed to redirecting to the other pages.
Another version of the relevant function was this:

```
blogapp.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/loginfailed'}),
     (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

but did not work either.

I have also tried several versions of GoogleStrategy, including the ones returning a done(parameter1, parameter2), but nothing happens.
It only prints the id, then stucks, and does not proceed to the next page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport needs to know the user was authenticated successfully by using the `done()` helper in the strategy callback.

```js
    function (token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile.id);
        done(null, profile);
    }
```

More information on the verify callback and `done` function:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/#verify-callback

Comment: That's why we should never use something before reading carefully the manual. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Done. I'm new here as you understand. Thank you, once again